# How do I set a range for a positive integer where the upper bound would be an input from another field?

Tags: django, validation

Suppose I have two variables A and B, both are positive integers. A can't be less than 1, B can't be greater than A.

In my models I have something like this:

```
A = models.PositiveIntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1)])
B = models.PositiveIntegerField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(A)])
```

This gives me the following error:

```
TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'PositiveIntegerField' and 'int'
```

Can someone suggest how to implement this kind of logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You perform validation that spans *multiple* fields in the [**`.clean()`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean):

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class MyModel(models.Model):
    a = models.PositiveIntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1)])
    b = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    def clean(self):
        if self.b > self.a:
            raise ValidationError('a should be greater than or equal to b.')
```

Since these are not field-specific errors, in case you use a `ModelForm`, it will render these errors as `{{ form.non_field_errors }}`. For more information, see the [*Rendering fields manually* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually).

You can make it specific to a field by passing the `ValidationError` a dictionary with as key the name of the field:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class MyModel(models.Model):
    a = models.PositiveIntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1)])
    b = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    def clean(self):
        if self.b > self.a:
            raise ValidationError({'b': 'a should be greater than or equal to b.'})
```

Comment: Thanks, I think the last line should be: `raise ValidationError('a should be greater than or equal to b.')` though? Also, the error message is not displayed for some reason.

Comment: @GeorgeB: did you use Django form (and render the form errors as well)?

Comment: I used Django ModelForm and yes I rendered form errors in my template like so: `{{ form.non_field_errors }}` and `{{ form.A.errors }}`.

Comment: @GeorgeB: what if you `print(form.errors)` in the view?

Comment: Ok, it is working, the error message is being displayed, but on the top of the page and not at the input field as it should be.

Comment: @GeorgeB: you can pass a dictionary with as key the field name if you want to use field-specific errors.